# Campagnolo: Can I run an 11 speed chain on my 10 speed chainrings?

Tags: chainring, derailleur-front, campagnolo

I have a bike with 10 speed front derailleur and chainrings.
The cassette, rear derailleur and shifter will all be 11 speed.
Can I run an 11 speed chain on this? Everything is Campagnolo.

Thanks

Comment: Are you implying that you have a 11 speed cassette and rear shifter and derailleur?

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus no, the cassette, rear derailleur and shifter will all be 11 speed. Edited the post to reflect these details.

Comment: I meant 11, comment fixed

Comment: You do need to specify that it's a Campy crank, which from your other post I assume it is. This entire question is about how this plays with Campy, which is distinctly different in this one regard than everything else because the Campy 10 chain is so much wider than Shimano/SRAM/KMC/etc.

Comment: @NathanKnutson yes, it is a 10 speed Campagnolo crankset.

Comment: @NathanKnutson Actually, early Campy 10s chains were wider at 6.1 or 6.2mm (I think) vs 5.88mm or thereabouts for Shimano and SRAM. However, Campy later went to 5.9mm. They may designate these as ultra narrow chains. By now the older wider chains are likely all used up. I don't know when this change occurred, but I think it was mid or late 2000s. Some corroboration here: https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1220/1-bicycle-chains-compatibility/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very likely yes this will work fine.  The main risks are

- that it is "out of spec" by the manufacturer so a warranty claim might be rejected
- 11 speed chain is narrower than 10 speed so the FD's cage will be a little wider - meaning the shifter has to move a little more to nudge the chain over
- the tolerance changes can increase the risk of a dropped chain on the inside, between, or outside of the chainrings.

Though I've successfully used 9 speed chain on what started as a 5 speed triple chainset, and its still working fine (though its friction shifting which may disguise some shifting issues.)

Answer (score 3):

So I had an 11-speed Record chain as well as 11-speed Campagnolo Centaur shifters and rear derailleur installed on the bike and all is working well! No issues with the chainrings or front derailleur - shifts great.